# how to update the branch in an existing devops pull request?

Tags: azure-devops

Creating a pull request from your feature branch is easy.

Then you do some more fixes to your feature branch, and push back to origin.

The pull request is still pointing at an old version of your branch.

How do you update the feature request to the latest version of your feature branch?

We can create a new PR, but then you have to fill out all the info again, and you lost the PR review history.

IS there another way?

Comment: *The pull request is still pointing at an old version of your branch.*. No, it is not.

Comment: Unfortunately, for us it definitely is.  If this is not expected behaviour, then we must have something configured wrongly or some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to update the pull request to include the follow-up commits. Once you've created a pull request, you can push commits from your topic branch to add them to your existing pull request. These commits will appear in chronological order within your pull request and the changes will be visible in the "Files changed" tab.

Comment: Hmm, this doesnt work for us.  Our PRs in devops dont get the new commits. If I browse the repo in devops on the corresponding branch, I see the latest commits. But these are not reflected in that same branch which is in the PR.  Currently, the only solution we found is to create new PR every time you update the branch of a PR, e.g. as the result of a code review.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and was able to solve it in following ways:
On the PR go to More Actions -> Restart merge.

This saved me some time.